# Using multithreading in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to create 4 car objects that are each on separate threads but I can't figure out how to get each of the cars to move at different speeds that are inputted by the user.

Here's my main program:

```
public class Racecar extends JApplet {

public Racecar() {
  setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
  JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
  JLabel car1 = new JLabel("Car 1:");
  panel1.add(car1);
  JTextField jtfcar1 = new JTextField(3);
  panel1.add(jtfcar1);
  JLabel car2 = new JLabel("Car 2:");
  panel1.add(car2);
  JTextField jtfcar2 = new JTextField(3);
  panel1.add(jtfcar2);
  JLabel car3 = new JLabel("Car 3:");
  panel1.add(car3);
  JTextField jtfcar3 = new JTextField(3);
  panel1.add(jtfcar3);
  JLabel car4 = new JLabel("Car 4:");
  panel1.add(car4);
  JTextField jtfcar4 = new JTextField(3);
  panel1.add(jtfcar4);
  add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

  JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
  panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
  DrawCar car = new DrawCar(1);
  panel2.add(car);
  add(panel2);

  JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
  panel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
  DrawCar car10 = new DrawCar(2);
  panel3.add(car10);
  add(panel3);

  JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
  panel4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
  DrawCar car11 = new DrawCar(3);
  panel4.add(car11);
  add(panel4);

  JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
  panel5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
  DrawCar car12 = new DrawCar(4);
  panel5.add(car12);
  add(panel5);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Racecar applet = new Racecar();
applet.init();
applet.start();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setTitle("");
frame.getContentPane().add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(400, 320);
frame.setVisible(true);


    // Create tasks
Runnable race1 = new DrawCar(1);
Runnable race2 = new DrawCar(2);
Runnable race3 = new DrawCar(3);
Runnable race4 = new DrawCar(4);

// Create threads
Thread thread1 = new Thread(race1);
Thread thread2 = new Thread(race2);
Thread thread3 = new Thread(race3);
Thread thread4 = new Thread(race4);

// Start threads
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();
thread4.start();
}

}
```

And here is my DrawCar method:

```
public class DrawCar extends JPanel implements ActionListener, Runnable {
private int delay = 10;
private Timer timer = new Timer(delay, this);
private int x1 = 20;
private int y1 = 22;
int r = (int)(Math.random()*256);
int q =(int)(Math.random()*256);
int b = (int)(Math.random()*256);
Color color = new Color(r, q, b);

public DrawCar(int x) { 
 timer.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  repaint();
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
g.setColor(color);
g.fillRoundRect(x1, y1, 75, 20, 10, 10);
g.fillArc(x1, y1 - 10, 50, 15, 0, 180);
g.fillOval(x1 + 2, y1 + 10, 20,20);
g.fillOval(x1 + 40, y1 + 10, 20, 20); 
if(x1 > getWidth()) {
     x1 = -100;
 }
    x1 += 1;

repaint(); 
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  return new Dimension(400, 320);
  }

private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   repaint();
}
}

public void run() {

  try {

  //int x = Racecar.getSpeed();

  Thread.sleep(1500);

  }
  catch (InterruptedException ex) {
  }

}

}
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to create 4 car objects that are each on separate threads"* - Well there's a problem right there. Instead, you should have a single thread which updates all the cars, each car, been an object, would have it's own speed property which would determine how much of change would occur on each cycle

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to create 4 car objects that are each on separate threads

Well there's a problem right there. There's a few reasons, probably the most significant is Swing isn't thread safe, so you're risking race conditions and dirty read/writes between the different threads which could have the "model" out of sync with the UI.

Instead, you should have a single thread which updates all the cars, each car, been an object, would have it's own speed property which would determine how much of change would occur on each cycle.

I wouldn't create a `JPanel` for each car, but instead, I would have a single `JPanel` which was responsible for painting all the cars.  This will afford you with better performance, but is also a lot easier to handle.

I'd start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Because of the single threaded nature of Swing, I'd also have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of trying to use threads.

This is an incredibly bad idea...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //...
    if(x1 > getWidth()) {
        x1 = -100;
    }
    x1 += 1;
    repaint(); 
}
```

Painting can occur for a lot of different reasons, many of which you don't control, so your objects could be moving faster not because of what the thread is doing, but because of what the system is doing each time it paints the component, so basically, it's out of control.

Painting is for painting, nothing else, you should never update the state the component from within a paint method.

Also, you should never call `repaint` (directly or indirectly) from within a paint method, this is going very quickly cause a run-away repaint cycle which will eventually consume all the CPU cycles.

Maybe something more like...

[image: Race]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Car> cars;

        public TestPane() {
            cars = new ArrayList<>(4);
            Color[] colors = new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA};
            int yPos = 0;
            int speed = 1;
            for (Color color : colors) {
                Car car = new Car(new Point(0, yPos += 30), speed++, color);
                cars.add(car);
            }
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (Car car : cars) {
                        car.update(getSize());
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Car car : cars) {
                car.paint(g2d);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }   

    public class Car {
        private Point location;
        private Dimension size;

        private int speed;
        private Color color;

        public Car(Point location, int speed, Color color) {
            this.location = location;
            this.speed = speed;
            this.color = color;

            size = new Dimension(20, 20);
        }

        public void update(Dimension bounds) {
            location.x += speed;
            if (location.x + size.width > bounds.width) {
                location.x = bounds.width - size.width;
                speed = 0;
            }
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fill(new Rectangle(location, size));
        }

    }

}
```

would help

Answer (score 0):

Running each car on its own thread won't work if you want their speeds to be regular. There is no guarantee as to when and how often the OS will schedule any given thread. It could be that car A gets scheduled twice as much as car B, so even if they are the same speed it will seem that car A goes much faster.

Also be aware that threads are NOT compatible with swing.

If you must use threads, see this tutorial on how to do it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html

In my opinion you should not use threads at all for this task - just update the cars in a loop. If you must use threads, at least use one thread to update all of the cars.